# Jena SPARQL API using inference rules file

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, semantic-web, jena-rules

I am working with Jena SPARQL API, and I want to execute queries on my RDF files after applying inference rules. I created a `.rul` file that contains all my rules; now I want to run those rules and execute my queries. When I used OWL, I proceeded this way:

```
     OntModel model1 = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec..OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF);

    // read the RDF/XML file
    model1.read( "./files/ontology.owl", "RDF/XML" );
    model1.read( "./files/data.rdf", "RDF/XML" );

    // Create a new query
    String queryString =        
      ".....my query";
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
    QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model1);
    ResultSet results =  qe.execSelect();
    ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
```

I want to do the same thing with inferences rules, i.e., load my `.rul` file like this:

```
model1.read( "./files/rules.rul", "RDF/XML" );
```

This didn't work with `.rul` files, the rules are not executed. Any ideas how to load a `.rul` file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What problem are you running into, exactly?

Comment: I edited my question. In fact, I want to load a .rul file and execute the rules iside it. I tried same method  as OWL files but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Jena rules aren't RDF, and you don't read them into a model.

RDFS is RDF, and it is implemented internally using rules.

To build an inference model:

```
    Model baseData = ... 
    List<Rule> rules = Rule.rulesFromURL("file:YourRulesFile") ;
    Reasoner reasoner = new GenericRuleReasoner(rules);
    Model infModel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, baseData) ;
```

See `ModelFactory` for other ways to build models (e.g., RDFS inference) directly.